# What is Microsoft Application Verifier for?

Tags: windows, application-verifier

I've got Microsoft [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) installed with some SDK. How do I make any use of it, practically? Are there any simple examples/explanations?

Comment: [Here's a practical example of AppVerifier catching a use-after-free but](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50861106/12597)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Application Verifier attaches to your application and does various things to try to make your application crash, like simulating low-resource situations. It also makes various APIs much more strict and will do things like record who leaked handles, etc.

You should definitely be using it with every desktop application or service, though to get a lot of the information out of it, you need to attach [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) to your process, and Application Verifier will dump more information out to the debug window.