# Application Verifier reports access violation in call to ShellExecuteEx

Tags: winapi, windows-shell, application-verifier

### Short Version

Application Verifier says there is an access violation when running the code:

```
var
   shi: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
   shi := Default(TShellExecuteInfo);
   shi.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
   shi.lpFile := PChar('C:\Windows');
   ShellExecuteEx(@shi);
end;
```

What's wrong with it?

## Long Version

I'm running my application under the [Application Verifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/application-verifier), with the option to detect heap corruption enabled:

- **Heaps**: Checks the heap errors.

[image]

During the call to **ShellExecuteEx**, an exception comes up, indicating that there is heap corruption.

Running inside a debugger allows me to decode the exception:

```
ExceptionAddress: 0000000074b254ad (KERNELBASE!ParseURLW+0x000000000000002d)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000008e26fe8
Attempt to read from address 0000000008e26fe8
```

Running *outside* a debugger, the application crashes (WerFault takes a post-mortem and the process dies).

What is wrong with the code?

## Example

```
program ShellExecuteTestApp;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.ShellAPI;

var
    shi: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
    try
        shi := Default(TShellExecuteInfo);
        shi.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
        shi.lpFile := PChar('C:\Windows');

        WriteLn('shi.cbSize: '+IntToStr(shi.cbSize));
        WriteLn('shi.lpFile: "'+shi.lpFile+'"');
        ShellExecuteEx(@shi);
    except
        on E: Exception do
            Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
end.
```

Before crashing, it outputs:

```
shi.cbSize: 60
shi.lpFile: "C:\Windows"
```

I thought perhaps it was the [common bug from **CreateProcess**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11339245/12597), so i made sure the `lpFile` was writable:

```
var
   file: string;
   shi: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
   file := 'C:\Windows';
   UniqueString({var} file);

   shi := Default(TShellExecuteInfo);
   shi.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
   shi.lpFile := PChar(file);
   ShellExecuteEx(@shi);
end;
```

### Memory dumps

Using a 32-bit build (to keep pointers easier to read), the memory being passed to **ShellExecuteEx**

```
00423EBC   0000003C  cbSize         60 bytes
           00000000  fMask          SEE_MASK_DEFAULT
           00000000  Wnd            null
           00000000  lpVerb         null
           0041C600  lpFile         ==> 0x0041C60C
           00000000  lpParameters   null
           00000000  lpDirectory    null 
           00000001  nShow          SW_NORMAL
           00000000  hInstApp       0
           00000000  lpIDList       null
           00000000  lpClass        null
           00000000  hkeyClass      0
           00000000  dwHotKey       0
           00000000  hMonitor       null
           00000000  hProcess       null
```

With the one pointer to a wide char:

```
0041C60C  43 00 3A 00 5C 00 57 00  C.:.\.W.
0041C614  69 00 6E 00 64 00 6F 00  i.n.d.o.
0041C61C  77 00 73 00 00 00 00 00  w.s.....
```

It then calls:

```
ShellExecuteTestApp.dpr.29: ShellExecuteEx(@shi);
0041C51F 68BC3E4200       push $00423ebc       ;push address of shi structure
0041C524 E85BD6FFFF       call ShellExecuteEx  ;call imported function

Winapi.ShellAPI.pas.1798: function ShellExecuteEx; external shell32 name 'ShellExecuteExW';
00419B84 FF250C444200     jmp dword ptr [$0042440c] ;jump to ShellExecuteW inside shell32


shell32.ShellExecuteExW:
75520060 8BFF             mov edi,edi
75520062 55               push ebp
75520063 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
75520065 83E4F8           and esp,-$08
75520068 51               push ecx
75520069 53               push ebx
7552006A 56               push esi
7552006B 8B7508           mov esi,[ebp+$08]
7552006E 57               push edi
7552006F 833E3C           cmp dword ptr [esi],$3c
75520072 7540             jnz $755200b4
75520074 8B5E04           mov ebx,[esi+$04]
75520077 F7C300011000     test ebx,$00100100
7552007D 7427             jz $755200a6
7552007F 8BCE             mov ecx,esi
75520081 E836000000       call $755200bc --> failure is this way
```

And then there's a lot of stuff i can't follow, until the error finally happens in **[ParseUrlW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773825(v=vs.85).aspx)**:

```
HRESULT ParseURL(
  _In_    LPCTSTR   pcszUrl,
  _Inout_ PARSEDURL *ppu
);
```

with dump:

```
KERNELBASE.ParseURLW:
74B25480 8BFF             mov edi,edi
74B25482 55               push ebp
74B25483 8BEC             mov ebp,esp         ;save stack pointer
74B25485 8B4508           mov eax,[ebp+$08]   ;restore pcszUrl into EAX
74B25488 83EC0C           sub esp,$0c
74B2548B 85C0             test eax,eax        ;test that pcszUrl param supplied
74B2548D 0F8493010000     jz $74b25626
```

---

**Note**: At this moment <kbd>EAX</kbd> contains address 0x0908BFE8:

```
0908BFE8: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........
```

The supplied pcszUrl string is empty? Actually no, the address is invalid. But we don't know that yet until the code tries to touch it

---

```
74B25493 57               push edi            ;save EDI
74B25494 8B7D0C           mov edi,[ebp+$0c]   ;get PARSEDURL into edi
74B25497 85FF             test edi,edi
74B25499 0F8410630300     jz $74b5b7af
```

---

**Note**: At this moment <kbd>edi</kbd> contains 0977FBDC

```
PARSEDURL structure
0977FBCD   00000018   cbSize      24 bytes
           753F5BC0   pszProtocol [uninitialized junk]
           0977FEC4   cchProtocol [uninitialized junk]
           092ECFC8   pszSuffix   [uninitialized junk]
           78E6E41E   cchSuffix   [uninitialized junk]
           0977FE98   nScheme     [uninitialized junk]
```

---

```
74B2549F 833F18           cmp dword ptr [edi],$18  ;test that struct size is what we expect (24 bytes)
74B254A2 0F8507630300     jnz $74b5b7af

74B254A8 53               push ebx           ;save ebx
74B254A9 8BD0             mov edx,eax        ;save pcszUrl into edx
74B254AB 33DB             xor ebx,ebx     

74B254AD 0FB700           movzx eax,[eax]    ;Attempt to copy 4 bytes of the string into EAX (access violation)
```

The code tries to copy the first word from 0x0908BFE8 using [Move with Zero-Extend](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVZX.html). But that address is invalid, giving the access violation:

> access violation at 0x74b254ad: read of address 0x0908bfe8

So somewhere in the code of **ShellExecuteExW**, it sets up an invalid call to **ParseUrlW**.

### WinDBG

32-bit WinDbg, debugging 32-bit application, with symbols:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for image00400000

FAULTING_IP: 
KERNELBASE!ParseURLW+2d
74b254ad 0fb700          movzx   eax,word ptr [eax]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 74b254ad (KERNELBASE!ParseURLW+0x0000002d)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 07634fe8
Attempt to read from address 07634fe8

CONTEXT:  00000000 -- (.cxr 0x0;r)
eax=07634fe8 ebx=00000000 ecx=07634fe8 edx=07634fe8 esi=00000000 edi=093dfbdc
eip=74b254ad esp=093dfbb4 ebp=093dfbc8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
KERNELBASE!ParseURLW+0x2d:
74b254ad 0fb700          movzx   eax,word ptr [eax]       ds:002b:07634fe8=????

FAULTING_THREAD:    00003ff4
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ
PROCESS_NAME:       image00400000
ERROR_CODE:         (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.
EXCEPTION_CODE:     (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  07634fe8
READ_ADDRESS:       07634fe8 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
shell32!GetUrlSchemeW+28
754c66be 85c0            test    eax,eax

NTGLOBALFLAG:                2000100
APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  80000001
APP:                         image00400000
ANALYSIS_VERSION:            6.3.9600.17237 (debuggers(dbg).140716-0327) x86fre
PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:       INVALID_POINTER_READ
BUGCHECK_STR:                APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_READ
LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:       from 754c66be to 74b254ad

STACK_TEXT:  
093dfbc8 754c66be 07634fe8 093dfbdc 00000000 KERNELBASE!ParseURLW+0x2d
093dfbf8 75522df8 0746fff0 07604f68 00000002 shell32!GetUrlSchemeW+0x28
093dfe98 75522b1a 093dfec4 00000000 0746fff0 shell32!CShellExecute::CreateParsingBindCtx+0x1d6
093dfecc 755224da 00000000 0746fff0 00000000 shell32!CShellExecute::ParseOrValidateTargetIdList+0x37
093dfef0 7551fd5a 093dff80 768b983a 07604f68 shell32!CShellExecute::_DoExecute+0x40
093dfef8 768b983a 07604f68 768b9770 768b9770 shell32!<lambda_e76b82c5cb7f9f82cbe0fd97ad5190bf>::<lambda_invoker_stdcall>+0x1a
093dff80 73d08484 0019fd94 73d08460 21439000 shcore!_WrapperThreadProc+0xca
093dff94 772c2fea 0019fd94 25ae5778 00000000 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
093dffdc 772c2fba ffffffff 772dec22 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
093dffec 00000000 768b9770 0019fd94 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


STACK_COMMAND:       .cxr 0x0 ; kb
SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1
SYMBOL_NAME:         shell32!GetUrlSchemeW+28
FOLLOWUP_NAME:       MachineOwner
MODULE_NAME:         shell32
IMAGE_NAME:          shell32.dll
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:   INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_shell32.dll!GetUrlSchemeW
BUCKET_ID:     
APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_READ_shell32!GetUrlSchemeW+28
ANALYSIS_SOURCE:     UM
FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:invalid_pointer_read_c0000005_shell32.dll!geturlschemew
FAILURE_ID_HASH:     {89d9bcf0-5ef6-4e90-df6b-f05dc028e062}
Followup:            MachineOwner
---------
```

### Bonus Reading

- [Access Violation ShellExecute in delphi7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228032/access-violation-shellexecute-in-delphi7)

Comment: Your code is fine. I suspect that ShellExecuteEx is trying to read one of the strings that is permitted to be NULL. Try setting them to be `''` until the verifier is happy. Or look at the address that the verifier returns to work out which field is being accessed with a first chance exception.

Comment: First-chance exceptions are not the exceptions you should worry about, unless they are followed by a second-chance exception. If all you see is a first-chance exception, then someone was prepared for it, and handled it already. Not unlikely for `ShellExecuteEx`, with all the foreign code it runs while servicing your request. You should probably have a look at address `0x74B254AD` to find the faulting module.

Comment: @IInspectable I can turn off first-chance exceptions, leaving on detection of Heap Corruption. I then no longer see (helpful) first chance exceptions, and instead get a lovely crash when the code violates the heap in a most inappropriate manner.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe, that both events are related?

Comment: The detection of heap corruption throws an exception. The exception is unhandled, and will crash the application. The *first-chance* exception option gives me informative exception information as an OutputDebugString. Alternatively i can disable detailing reporting of *first chance exceptions*, and let the application crash. I can then use the post-mortem debugger to get the same information that the *First Chance Exception* info gave me. *tl;dr: The first-chance exception option is a red herring, and i shall remove references to it in the question to avoid confusing people.

Comment: Maybe you should call `CoInitializeEx` before calling ShellExecuteEx? Also, does the AV happen in your code, might be some shell extension etc?

Comment: You didn't initialize many of the members of `shi`. Perhaps `ShellExecute` is picking up uninitialized garbage? (I see other people explicitly clearing the `TShellExecuteInfo`.)

Comment: @Raymond The assignment of Default(...) zero initialized the record. All members are initialized.

Comment: Okay, thanks for explaining. I know Pascal but not Delphi. Can you share a stack trace (and OS version information)? Or you can dig the Watson failure ID out of the event log and I can try to hunt for it on the back-end.

Comment: @RaymondChen I added some dumps and traced somwhat into ShellExecuteExW; the failure happens internally during the call the ParseUrlW where it supplies an invalid address to the pcszUrl. It seems to succeed if i add a trailing backslash; change the filename from `"C:\Windows"` to `"C:\Windows\"

Comment: [Link to test app binary](https://nofile.io/f/6mX3znCzGFV/ShellExecuteTestApp.exe)

Comment: @RaymondChen **Report Id**: `a8a75eb7-d024-4d0b-9f2d-d037368a8ae0`. Windows 10.0.17134 Build 17134.

Comment: [Zipped mini-dump](https://nofile.io/f/8jk2HbUkQR9/ShellExecuteTestApp_20180615_134536_12224_16768.zip)

Comment: Somehow I couldn't download the mini-dump, but the report ID gave me access to the Watson crash dump. This is a use-after free bug in the OS that occurs if we had to fiddle with the name. It looks like you have a workaround (add the trailing backslash); I'll file a bug to get this fixed in Windows. Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: @RaymondChen. Thanks!  Bonus: [Time travel debugging trace zip](https://nofile.io/f/5WGb4FyTURs/ShellExecuteFail-TimeTravelDebuggingTrace.zip) *(i can't imagine anyplace else to put them that your IT would allow)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RaymondChen said, it's a bug in Windows 10.

- I only encountered it because [Application Verifier](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031224-00/?p=41363) caught it.
- it's a [one-in-a-million chance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2004/03/30/one-in-a-million-is-next-tuesday/) that you'd actually ever encounter it in the wild

Raymond's too modest to accept reputation; so i use his answer as my own.

Answer (score 0):

A code that has been running OK for years started to fail with an Access Violation in KernelBase.dll. I think that some Win10 upgrade must have changed something on that dll.

I found this Question and thanks to the comment of @David Heffernan I added the line

```
ExecInfo.lpParameters := '';
```

and that solved the problem.

```
var
  ExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;  
begin
  ExecInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ExecInfo);
  ExecInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  ExecInfo.Wnd := 0; // Handle;
  ExecInfo.lpVerb := 'runas';    
  ExecInfo.lpFile := PChar(sPath + sFileName);
  ExecInfo.lpDirectory := PChar(sPath);
  ExecInfo.nShow := SW_HIDE; 
  ExecInfo.lpParameters := '';  //PJR@20210125  Added this line to avoid AccessViolation in KernelBase.dll due to a bug in some version of Win10.

  if ShellExecuteEx(@ExecInfo) then
    (...)
```

Comment: The issue in this code that nobody is initializing `ExecInfo`. Anything not defined is undefined, and you cannot pass undefined parameters to a function. [It's one of the basic rules of programming](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060320-13/?p=31853). The old-fashioned way is to call `ZeroMemory(@execInfo, sizeof(execInfo))`.